# Run Java with third party JAR

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I've been trying for 1 week to run a simple java program using third party jar, but I keep getting error. Just now I try this program as below

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
public class HelloWorld{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                String x = "abcd";
                System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize(x));
        }
}
```

and when I try to compile and run, command prompt return error as below

```
c:\training\java\exercise>javac -cp ".;./org/apache/commons/lang3/commons-lang3-3.9.jar" HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize(x));
```

I take this example from this sites as for reference https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/compile-and-run-java-in-command-line-with-external-jars/

can anyone help me how to solve this? Thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1kTd.png)

Comment: are you running this on windows?

Comment: It looks like you are pointing to incorrect location of `commons-lang3-3.9.jar`. Try putting both: `HelloWorld.java` and `commons-lang3-3.9.jar` in the same directory and run: `javac -cp commons-lang3-3.9.jar HelloWorld.java`

Comment: @VinitPillai yes, I'm using windows

Comment: @Oo.oO I already try using your solution but I keep getting the same error as mention above

Comment: @Oo.oO refer to my updates on the screenshot of my cmd

Comment: Just out of the curiosity. Is there any possibility that your `JAR` file is broken? Sometimes, when people download `JAR` files using `wget` and `curl` and there is a redirect, you end up with `html` code inside. Can you open `commons-lang3-3.9.jar` and see what's inside?

Comment: @Oo.oO i'm not sure if this jar file is broken or not because I downloaded this file from this sites https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about just that [available here](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/compile-and-run-java-in-command-line-with-external-jars/)

I assume you're on Windows as the working folder has disk `C:` so it should be Windows.

Bottom line it looks like you're mixing the notions of folder and jar.
Make sure that the folder `C:\training\java\exercise` contains both `HelloWorld.java` and `commons-lang3-3.9.jar`

Also make sure you're in the `C:\training\java\exercise` folder

Then compile like this:

```
 javac -cp ".;./commons-lang3-3.9.jar" HelloWorld.java
```

Now this should create `HelloWorld.class` file

Now Run the java process:

```
java  -cp ".;./commons-lang3-3.9.jar" HelloWorld
```

Comment: Do I need to put the .jar file and .java file in the same location?

Comment: I try to implement your solution in my works but it return the same error as mention above.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of my cmd above as your reference

Comment: You don't have to put the jar and java at the same location, but then you should provide a path to the jar.... Check also that the jar you use is not corrupted or something (you can open it with WinRar / WinZip) and check

Comment: Please try using ";" instead of ":" - it has worked for me with java13 on windows, although  the ":" didn't...

Comment: I already check the Jar file with WinRar and I can confirmed it is not corrupted. I already try this one but it still not working `javac -cp ".;./commons-lang3-3.9.jar" HelloWorld.java`

Comment: I rearrange my file structure and rename some of the files just now and try to use your solution and it's working. Thank you so much!